# handle a function that returns a promise or a null value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, ecmascript-5

I have defined a function as following :

```
function getCurrentComponent(){
    if($rootRouter._currentInstruction){
        return $rootRouter.recognize($rootRouter._currentInstruction.urlPath).then(function (data) {
            return data.component.componentType;
        });
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

To call this function I did as following :

```
factory.getCurrentComponent().then(function (data) {
    ...
});
```

The problem is when the `getCurrentComponent` function returns a null value, the following error is generated :

> Cannot read property 'then' of null

How can I solve this ?

## Edit:

I forgot to say that I'm limited to use ES5, so I can't work with the object `Promise`

Comment: don't chain it? return a promise?

Comment: Return a rejected Promise instead of `null`

Comment: To avoid getting answers with ES6 promises, avoid the [tag:promise] tag. Use the [tag:angular-promise] tag instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cant use the object [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in ES5.

Use the [AngularJS $q Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
function getCurrentComponent(){
    if($rootRouter._currentInstruction){
        return $rootRouter.recognize($rootRouter._currentInstruction.urlPath).then(function (data) {
            return data.component.componentType;
        });
    }else{
        ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶n̶u̶l̶l̶;̶
        return $q.reject(null);
    }
}
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

The [$q Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is a [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/)-compliant implementation of promises/deferred objects thst is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

Answer (score 7):

Use `Promise.reject()` function.

```
function getCurrentComponent() {
  if ($rootRouter._currentInstruction) {
    return $rootRouter.recognize($rootRouter._currentInstruction.urlPath).then(function(data) {
      return data.component.componentType;
    });
  } else {
    return Promise.reject('_currentInstruction is fale');
  }
}

factory.getCurrentComponent().then(function(data) {
  ...
}).catch(function(e) {
  console.log(e); // Output: _currentInstruction is fale
});
```

## Resource

- [`Promise.reject()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject)

---

If you're unable to use `Promise` you can return an object with a function `then`.

```
function getCurrentComponent() {
  if ($rootRouter._currentInstruction) {
    return $rootRouter.recognize($rootRouter._currentInstruction.urlPath).then(function(data) {
      return data.component.componentType;
    });
  } else {
    var helperThen = { then: function(fn) { fn(null) } };
    return helperThen;
  }
}

factory.getCurrentComponent().then(function(data) {
  // Check if data is null.
  ...
});
```

Comment: I cant use the object Promise in ES5.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki Unfortunately no, Promise was released in ES6.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki see the updated answer.  Check if that approach can resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the function to use a `Promise`.

```
function getCurrentComponent(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      if($rootRouter._currentInstruction){
          resolve( $rootRouter.recognize($rootRouter._currentInstruction.urlPath).then(function (data) {
              return data.component.componentType;
          }));
    } else{
        reject(null);
    })
}
```

Now you can check `resolve` and `reject` with then() function,

```
factory.getCurrentComponent().then(function (resolved) {
    //handle success here
}, function(rejected) {
   // handle rejection here
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I cant use the object Promise in ES5.

Comment: If you can use a polyfill. https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill

Comment: neither I can do that, I'm limited to use ES5.